# SignalR sqlDependency

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I need SQL Dependency change on a gridview displaying all rows that are changed or old data.  Can anybody help me?

Here is my script:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var notify = $.connection.notificationsHub;
            notify.client.displayNotification = function (msg) {
                $("#newData").html(msg);
            };
            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    </script> </head> <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView id="newData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            </asp:GridView>

 public void SendNotifications()
        {
            string message = string.Empty;
            string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Message] FROM [dbo].[tb]";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                       while (reader.Read())
                             {
                               message = reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            }
            NotificationsHub nHub = new NotificationsHub();
            nHub.NotifyAllClients(message);
        }
        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                SendNotifications();
            }
        }
```